# Password verify not giving any output in return and showing no error

Tags: php, html, sqlite

Password_verfiy is not working at all even if i hardcode the values of the password and the hash itself. It is working in a similar program but that program is without prameterized queries

```php
<?php
include 'db.php';
session_start();
$numrows=null;
$hpass=null;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $query = $connection->prepare('Select password from users where username=?');
        $query->bind_param("s", $username);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($hpass);
        while ($query->fetch()) {
            $numrows++;
        }

        $query->close();
        //$query->fetch();
        //$numofrows=$query->num_rows;
        if ($numrows == 1) {
            if (password_verify($password, $hpass)) {
                $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                header("location:todo.php");
            } else {
                header("location:1.php");
            }
        } else {
            header("location:2.php");
        }
    }
    else {
        header("location:not.php");
    }
}
```

```php
$password = $_GET['pass'];
        $hpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query=$connection->prepare("insert into users (username,password) values (?,?)");
        $query->bind_param('ss',$name,$hpass);
        if ($query->execute()) {
            $query->close();
            header('location:index.php');
        } else {
            header('location:not.php');
        }
```

Comment: Well, do some basic debugging - which `if`s do you enter?

Comment: When storing the passwords to database initially, do you store the hash generated with password_hash() function? If you are using custom hashing algorithm, password_verify() will not work.

Comment: I enter the if($num==1) but it always end up in me getting redirected to 1.php that is the else of password_verify

Comment: using password_hash() function

Comment: Then, what is `$hpass`?

Comment: $hpass is basically the hashed passord thats is coming from the output of the query

Comment: and if you echo out both $password and $hpass, do they match (visually inspecting them)?

Comment: What size is the column in which you store the passwords? It must be at least 60 characters wide.

Comment: Yes, you say it's hashed, but *what is its value*? Is the column big enough? Does it have a whitespace at the end? How do you hash it?

Comment: they cant match because one of them is hashed and the other isnt i have tried to even hardcode the values in password_verfiy but it isnt working

Comment: it is 255 characters

Comment: hashing it by the built in password_hash

Comment: I'm not great at backend dev, but with a quick Google, it looks like you're not using the password_verify() function correctly? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Then check how you insert that hash - do you do something to the password before you hash it?

Comment: Agreed with @Qirel, show us how you hash the password.

Comment: Added it above.

Comment: Uh, you're passing the original password in a GET? That doesn't have an effect on your issue, but you shouldn't do that.

Comment: the original password is on a completely diff page so it doesnt matter i think if it is get or post

Comment: It exposes the password to prying eyes, so yeah, it's important.

Comment: What do you get when you `echo $numrows;` after you increment?

Comment: Totally my bad Thankyou @JayBlanchard for he help and effort it was the get problem i didnt change it by mistake.

Comment: Thankyou @Qirel aswell